# Get index of substring

Tags: c, char, substring

I have **char * source**, and I want extract from it subsrting, that I know is beginning from symbols "abc", and ends where source ends. With **strstr** I can get the poiner, but not the position, and without position I don't know the length of the substring. How can I get the index of the substring in pure C?

Comment: You probably can do what you want just with pointers, with no worrying about lengths.

Comment: @Country - there's no reason why you can't vote (there just might be a limit to the frequency)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use pointer subtraction.

```
char *str = "sdfadabcGGGGGGGGG";
char *result = strstr(str, "abc");
int position = result - str;
int substringLength = strlen(str) - position;
```

Comment: oops `char *str = "abracabcabcabcabc"` :-)

Comment: ahh, his "source" string starts with abc then continues... :-)

Comment: Thanks all! I can't vote for some reason, so I just can say thank you

Answer (score 6):

`newptr - source` will give you the offset.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *source = "XXXXabcYYYY";
char *dest = strstr(source, "abc");
int pos;

pos = dest - source;
```

Comment: oops `source = "abracadabcabcabcabc"` :)

Comment: @pmg - doesn't matter - "starts with 'abc'" still creates the correct result as strstr() stops looking once it's successful

Comment: I'd allocate an array with malloc just to make the example more complete.  Of course, I'd also do some error checking too ;-)

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - you would, but you didn't ;)

Comment: Thanks all! I can't vote for some reason, so I just can say thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C version of the strpos function with an offset feature...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle, int offset);
int main()
{
    char *p = "Hello there all y'al, hope that you are all well";
    int pos = strpos(p, "all", 0);
    printf("First all at : %d\n", pos);
    pos = strpos(p, "all", 10);
    printf("Second all at : %d\n", pos);
}


int strpos(char *hay, char *needle, int offset)
{
   char haystack[strlen(hay)];
   strncpy(haystack, hay+offset, strlen(hay)-offset);
   char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
   if (p)
      return p - haystack+offset;
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the pointer to the first char of the substring, and the substring ends at the end of the source string, then:

- `strlen(substring)` will give you its length.
- `substring - source` will give you the start index.

Comment: Thanks all! I can't vote for some reason, so I just can say thank you

Answer (score 2):

Formally the others are right - `substring - source` is indeed the start index. But you won't need it: you would use it as index into `source`. So the compiler calculates `source + (substring - source)` as the new address - but just `substring` would be enough for nearly all use cases.

Just a hint for optimization and simplification.

Comment: Thanks all! I can't vote for some reason, so I just can say thank you

Answer (score 0):

A function to cut a word out out of a string by a start and end word

```
    string search_string = "check_this_test"; // The string you want to get the substring
    string from_string = "check";             // The word/string you want to start
    string to_string = "test";                // The word/string you want to stop

    string result = search_string;            // Sets the result to the search_string (if from and to word not in search_string)
    int from_match = search_string.IndexOf(from_string) + from_string.Length; // Get position of start word
    int to_match = search_string.IndexOf(to_string);                          // Get position of stop word
    if (from_match > -1 && to_match > -1)                                     // Check if start and stop word in search_string
    {
        result = search_string.Substring(from_match, to_match - from_match);  // Cuts the word between out of the serach_string
    }
```

Comment: The question is regarding C, not C++

Comment: In C++ there is easier way to do it - using string::Find method and string constructor string(const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos);