# How to return value using strstr function?

Tags: c

The question is to input two strings: S1 and S2. The objective is to find whether there exist a substring, and I know `strstr` can be used. If there exists a substring, print the index at S1 at which there is a match, else print -1 . Though I know if there is substring `strstr` returns the first index value, but I don't know how to use it.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[20],s2[20];
    char x;
    gets(s1);
    gets(s2);
    x=strstr(s1,s2);
    if(strstr(s1,s2)==NULL)
    printf("-1");
    else
    printf("%s",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guyz, Even I use a pointer, I get warning from compiler : Program: In function 'main':
Program:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strstr' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
Program:15:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strstr' [enabled by default]    Using dev cpp

Comment: Odd. Perhaps try `#include <strings.h>` instead (even though what you have should be correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` needs to be a pointer:

```
char *x;
```

Then:

```
x=strstr(s1,s2);
```

points to the location within `s1` of `s2`, or NULL. If you need the index, you can write:

```
int indx = x ? x - s1 : -1;
// ...
printf("%d\n", indx);
```

And by the way, as standard advice, you should use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`.

Comment: May be true but that's not an answer to the question

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's a fine answer

Comment: Also, had to use if statement rather than conditional operator as the online compiler had trouble with it!

Comment: @Roma: Odd about the online compiler. You mention in another question that you also use DEV c++ and turbo c++. How do they work here?

Comment: Actually, I use dev cpp as IDE in my system, and your code worked fine in that, and after that i had to submit my work, and the online compiler had some problem with it! And it was cleared when i used if statement

Answer (score 0):

your code almost works.
strstr returns the address which should be stored in a pointer.But you are storing in an character variable. So change the `char x` to `char *x`.

Answer (score 0):

from this post

Use pointer subtraction.

```
char *str = "sdfadabcGGGGGGGGG";
char *result = strstr(str, "abc");
int position = result - str;
int substringLength = strlen(str) - position;
```

[Get index of substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500892/get-index-of-substring)

Answer (score 0):

strstr() returns a char* pointer to the first occurence of substring. You need to subtract the starting address of the array to get the position as an index

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s1[20],s2[20];
    char *x;
    gets(s1);
    gets(s2);
    x=strstr(s1,s2);
    if(strstr(s1,s2)==NULL)
    printf("-1");
    else
    printf("%d",x-s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I'd advise you to refrain from using gets since it's a bad habit. Use fgets instead.