# Cannot find the position of an array of char in another array of char

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (){
    char prop[100], cuv[10], poz[100];
    fgets(prop, 100, stdin);
    fgets(cuv, 10, stdin);
    printf("%ld\n", strstr(prop, cuv) - prop);
    puts(prop);
    puts(cuv);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when i run it, and give it this input:

> Ana are mere

and this for the second string:

> are

the output is the following:

> -2752172

I used the same method as given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500892/get-index-of-substring). What should i change in the code?

Comment: Put this in a debugger, set a breakpoint, and step through it.

Comment: It would be more revealing to check the return value from `strstr()` than blindly use it.

Comment: I used debugging to check the return value from both strstr() and the subtraction. I didn't know the thing '\n' thing about fgets() and i'm feeling ashamed for that, but now i will surely keep that in mind, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `"are\n"` is not found within the string `"Ana are mere\n"`.
 
**Therefore `strstr` returns `NULL`.**

To get the expected output, you need to make sure you don't get the final Carriage Return (`\n`) on your search string.

Comment: That makes sense why the word "mere" gave the correct output, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I added the following line:
    cuv[strlen(cuv) - 1] = 0;

after second fgets() and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The both string include a new line, likes `"Ana are mere\n"` and `"are\n"` but there is no `"are\n"` in the string `"Ana are mere\n"` So that's why, we can removed the new line from `"are\n"`by using this statement `"cuv[strlen(cuv)-1] = '\0';"` after `"fgets(cuv, 10, stdin);"`